# Any idea how to redirect stdout from a big query to a file

Tags: google-bigquery

--apilog does not help as it has a different form of logging

Both the below options do not seem to work for me.

```
bq query --n=0 --append --apilog="/projects/strategic_data/apps/developments/cloudera-gcp-migration/airflow_home/dags_prod/scripts/bash/log.txt" 
--use_legacy_sql=false  --destination_table="abc.cde"  "SELECT * FROM abc.cde1"


bq query --n=0 --append --apilog="/projects/strategic_data/apps/developments/cloudera-gcp-migration/airflow_home/dags_prod/scripts/bash/log.txt"
--use_legacy_sql=false --destination_table="abc.cde"  "SELECT * FROM abc.cde1" >> $LOG_FILE
```

Comment: Hi gcp what excatlly not working for you?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am trying to redirect the stdout of the "bq command" to the  $LOG_FILE. But is not happening. I have also tried the --apilog option, but this doe not have the stdout but has the API log information which is not usefull to me.

Comment: You can't get the response into a file using a flag you can use a shell command to do this. The api log switch is for tracking the process and not for getting the data